# Publish .NET Maui app to specific app version using CLI

Tags: .net-maui, maui-blazor

I am trying to publish a .NET MAUI windows app to a specific app version (not windows version) using the command line interface, but I am unable to achieve this.

I know you can do it by using the *Publish -> Create App Package* method, but I want to automate the publishing using CLI. Thus, please do not provide answers with this method.

**What I have tried:**

In .csproj I have change the following without success:

```
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
<ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
```

I change the 1 to a 3 and the 1.0 to a 3.4 and no change.

Under Platform->Windows-> app.manifest

I have changed the version number in the following code without success:

```
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.5" name="Desktop.WinUI.app"/>
```

I have used --version  number in the publish command without success
e.g.
`dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release /p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 --version 1.0.0.6`

Even after all this I get a package with version number 1.0.0.1
[image]

Comment: Have you ever find a solution?

Comment: I have not find one.

Comment: I've done this: moved to .NET7 and, when changing version, I completely delete obj folder before compiling. It should work. Not sure if you need to move to NET7, maybe trying only to delete obj folder...